# Want to understand why I failed at review

Tags: discussion, review, low-quality-posts

I failed at [this review in the Low Quality Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/4104956).

After a first reading of that question, I saw nothing against that question. The post is not really "low quality", it is even quite well written and that is clear what the OP wants. I think the problem could be that it is off-topic (looking for a tool). Could you confirm that I should have click "close" for this reason to pass the test?

I'm feeling also a bit frustrated because this failure gave me a ban of 2 days, and because of this, I want to understand and avoid to fail next time!

Comment: What makes you think it's a high quality answer?  It's just a link to a tool and nothing else.  On this site an answer that does nothing but link to a product is a low quality answer.  You are correct that the question should be closed though.  These questions are a magnet for low quality/spam answers like these, which is why we close them.

Comment: Uh? I don't see an answer but a question in this review.

Comment: @LaurentG you are pointing to an answer review; did you scroll down accidentally before reviewing?

Comment: The linked review is to an answer. The question is simply shown below it for reference, but the answer is what is under review.

Comment: The question isn't exactly on-topic either @Jan.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards true. CV'd. My comment still stands, though.

Comment: @LaurentG because the answer is deleted, you won't see the actual answer that you reviewed as you don't have the rep to see deleted items.  It is an unfortunate side effect of known-bad audits.  As most known-bad audits involved deleted posts, it makes it difficult to go back to review why you failed if you don't have the rep to see.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thanks! Now I understand. Well that's not nice because I can't learn. I'm not sure now why I clicked "Looks good". Maybe I clicked too fast.

Comment: @LaurentG: FWIW, heres the answer you reviewed; http://i.stack.imgur.com/4RsHr.png

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO; see the screenshot you uploaded. That's not *actually* the answer that would have been shown!

Comment: @Matt Was in the process of uploading [the actual answer](http://i.imgur.com/zaeNyba.png)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That answer was spam. The only two answers by this user:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208456/looking-for-project-management-software-with-nested-subtasks-and-time-estimates/21703250#21703250
- [Simple project management tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261626/simple-project-management-tool/21406239#21406239)

both consist of just a link promoting a specific product. It was flagged as such and removed as a result. Spam-flagged and deleted answers become review audit cases like this.

Thanks for the reminder, because I've now destroyed that user and am removing the rest of this spam ring.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Fun fact: it appears this ring spammed this link 70 times on SO over the last month or so, and have hit other sites with it as well. Hopefully, the anti-spam system should be blocking them now.

Answer (score 4):

You have failed the review for making an answer that did not attempt to answer the question directly but instead suggested a tool as 'looking good'.

The answer was:

> I use proofhub to manage our team as well as clients. This tool helps a lot. You can try it.

The answer was not even an attempt to answer OP's question, it was just someone selling their commercial tool to people in Stack Overflow camouflaged as an answer attempt.

Like ben said, the question is not really on-topic either.